# Switch, case, try and catch in C# probelm

Tags: c#, switch-statement, try-catch

I am very new to C# programming. I wanted to catch the errors for example invalid input (not a number from 1-6) and print out a message stating the error. This is my code.

```
private static bool ManageStudents()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("========================");
        Console.WriteLine(" Choose an option:");
        Console.WriteLine("  1. Add a new student");
        Console.WriteLine("  2. View all students");
        Console.WriteLine("  3. Search students");
        Console.WriteLine("  4. Delete students");
        Console.WriteLine("  5. Update students");
        Console.WriteLine("  6. Back to main menu");
        Console.WriteLine("========================");
        Console.Write("\r\nPlease choose: ");

        try
        {
            switch (Console.ReadLine())
            {
                case "1":
                    AddStudents();
                    return true;
                case "2":
                    ViewStudents();
                    return true;
                case "3":
                    SearchStudents();
                    return true;
                case "4":
                    DeleteStudents();
                    return true;
                case "5":
                    UpdateStudents();
                    return true;
                case "6":
                    return false;
                default:
                    return true;
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("error message");
            Console.ReadLine();
            return true;
        }

    }
```

When I run the program the message "error message" didn't appear after I enter an invalid character.

Comment: What part of your code do you think will trigger the code in the `catch` block to run? Try doing some more reading on how [`try-catch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch) works.

Comment: `catch` block is entered if `try` block has `throw` an exception.
If you want to handle "Something out of the switch cases", you shall put it on `default` case. Don't use try catch in this case. Use other statement to check if input hits `default`.

Comment: you are returning a boolean from this method.. does true mean everything went through fine? Also, even if you change your statement in `default` to throw exception, you will still end up returning `true` from catch block. You probably want to return `false` from the catch block.

Comment: thank you I will do more reading on them! I just started C# few days ago I am just playing around with it these are very helpful comments I appreciate them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand the difference between when the default is called and when the catch is called. The default is called when non of the cases are true (here the number is not in the range 1-6). The catch is called when one of the functions inside the switch threw an exception (it could be AddStudents() or SearchStudents(), etc...).

Then you can handle your error more generically by adding a function receiving a message as parameter. So then you should have something like:

```
private static bool HandleError(string message) { // More generic handling
   Console.WriteLine(message);
   Console.ReadLine();
   return true;
}

private static bool ManageStudents()
{
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("========================");
        Console.WriteLine(" Choose an option:");
        Console.WriteLine("  1. Add a new student");
        Console.WriteLine("  2. View all students");
        Console.WriteLine("  3. Search students");
        Console.WriteLine("  4. Delete students");
        Console.WriteLine("  5. Update students");
        Console.WriteLine("  6. Back to main menu");
        Console.WriteLine("========================");
        Console.Write("\r\nPlease choose: ");

        try
        {
            switch (Console.ReadLine())
            {
                case "1":
                    AddStudents();
                    return true;
                case "2":
                    ViewStudents();
                    return true;
                case "3":
                    SearchStudents();
                    return true;
                case "4":
                    DeleteStudents();
                    return true;
                case "5":
                    UpdateStudents();
                    return true;
                case "6":
                    return false;
                default:
                    return HandleError("Out of range"); // Not in range 1-6
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e) // This catch exception happening in the all switch
        {
            return HandleError("Execution problem");
        }

    }
```

Comment: This also works thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
  default:
        return true;
```

You are telling it to return true without an error. You should change that to

```
  default:
        throw new Exception("Invalid Selection")
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
 default:
       return true;
```

with

```
 default:
       throw new Exception();
```

Comment: Your answer may be solve an issue but it's marked as low quality in this community as your answer contain only code not explanation. Please edit with details

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Answer (score 0):

You have pretty clear logic: *If given number not in the valid numbers list - print error message.*

So, don't use exception as part of the logic, exceptions are for the *exceptions*, for not expected cases. In addition throwing exception will be slightly more expensive than handle it with `switch case`.

[DA0007: Avoid using exceptions for control flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/da0007-avoid-using-exceptions-for-control-flow?view=vs-2017)

```
private static bool ManageStudents()
{
    switch (Console.ReadLine())
    {
        case "1":
            AddStudents();
            return true;
        case "2":
            ViewStudents();
            return true;
        case "3":
            SearchStudents();
            return true;
        case "4":
            DeleteStudents();
            return true;
        case "5":
            UpdateStudents();
            return true;
        case "6":
            return false;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid selection");
            return true;
    }
}
```

Now you can remove all `try .. catch` blocks.

Comment: sorry for the late respond! thank you so much this works!

Answer (score -1):

`default` when used in a `switch` statement is just that - a case to default to if no match is found. If you want the `try` block to fail, you'll need to throw an exception within the `default`.